# Modular promises and Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, promise, es6-promise

I have a bunch of functions that return promises that I want to make generalized, and so I write them like this:

```
function checkWebpageForReference(data){
    //checks a webpage for the reference in html
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fetchUrl(data.url, function(err, meta, body){
            if (err) { reject(err); } else {
                console.log(body)
                if (body.toString().indexOf(data.text) !== -1){
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject("Could not find quote");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

function takeScreenshot(data){
    //takes a screenshot of a webpage and saves it to the file system
    //TODO: Mouse coordinates
    data.id = shortid.generate();
    data.filename = data.id+'.png';
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        webshot(data.url, data.filename, { shotOffset: {left: data.mouseX, top: data.mouseY} }, function(err) {
            if (err) { reject(err); } else {
                resolve(data);   
            }
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

function uploadReferencePictureToS3(data){
    //uploads a picture to S3
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        s3.putObject({
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
            Key: data.id,
            Body: data.picturedata,
            ContentType: "image/jpg"
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) { reject(err); } else {
                resolve(data);   
            }
        }); 
    });
    return promise;
}

function saveNewReferenceToDb(data){
    //saves a new Reference to the database
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        new Reference({
            _id: data.id,
            url: data.url,
            text: data.text,
            screenshot_url: AWS_S3_URL + data.id,
            created_by: "Daniel"
        }).save(function(err, saved){
            if (err) { reject(err); } else {
                data.newReference = saved;
                resolve(data);   
            }
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

function readFile(data){
    //reads a file from the file structure and stores it in a variable
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        console.log(data);
        fs.readFile(data.filename, function(err, picturedata){
            console.log(picturedata);
            if (err) { reject(err); } else {
                data.picturedata = picturedata;
                resolve(data);   
            }
        }) ;
    });
    return promise;
}

function deleteFile(data){
    //deletes a file from the file structure
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fs.unlink(data.filename);
        resolve(data);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

I resolve data in each function because I plan to have a lot of these types of functions, and I don't know the order they'll be called in while chaining:

```
readfile(somedata)
.then(upload)
.then(delete)
.then(save)
//etc
```

This works fine until I have to do Promise.all:

```
   Promise.all([
        referenceTools.checkWebpageForReference(req.body),
        referenceTools.takeScreenshot(req.body)
    ])
    .then(function(results){
        utils.readFile(results[1])
        .then(referenceTools.uploadReferencePictureToS3)
        .then(utils.deleteFile)
        .then(referenceTools.saveNewReferenceToDb)
        .then(function(data){
            res.json(data.newReference);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            utils.errorHandler(err);
            res.send("There was an internal error. Please try again soon.");
        });  
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        utils.errorHandler(err);
        res.send("There was an internal error. Please try again soon.");
    });
    //my very ugly way of doing it
```

Using `Promise.all().then(upload)` gives me errors, because the new promise returned by Promise.all() is an object that contains both resolutions from `checkWebpageForReference` and `takeScreenshot`. Essentially, in `readFile`, I can't access `data` fields because the resulting promise is `[data, data]`.

Is there a pattern I can follow to help me achieve what I need to do? I need to make the promises modular providing them with as much data as possible.

Comment: So, do each of your functions follow some common interface? i.e. `prf1` and `prf2` both return objects that contain `new_variable1`? If not, how can you make `prf3` consistent if it doesn't know what it is receiving?

Comment: @MattWay There's not really a pattern they follow. I was leaving that up to their usage while chaining. I realize that makes it error prone, but I have yet to figure out a better way of doing it. The functions just assume that `data` contains a field that they ask for. If the chain is designed well, then they will. But I'm not sure how to standardize that.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like `prf3` to look like internally?

Comment: Because you are using the same object reference as input to each function, shouldn't your example above work? By grabbing `results[1]` aren't you simply choosing one of the [same] references?

Comment: @MattWay It does work, but I'm worried that it will cause confusion or problems in the future. If one of the functions in Promise.all() returns a field that the other one doesn't and vice versa, then it's hard to figure out what to do. I guess what I'm asking for is a way to keep track of variables that get passed down while chaining promises whilst being safe when using Promise.all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `.map()` over them like so:

```
Promise.all(...)
  .then(datas => Promise.all(datas.map(upload)));
```

Since you're on the server side, I highly recommend Bluebird as a drop-in replacement for native Promises. Then you can do:

```
Promise.all(...)
  .map(upload);
```

Comment: Beware this waits for everything to catch up at each step. It's generally faster to map first and Promise.all last, allowing all steps to run in parallel for each file. E.g.: `Promise.all(files.map(file => readfile(file).then(upload).then(delete).then(save))).then(d‌​atas => ...)`